# Adding Non-Linear source term to 2d Implicit MATLAB code

Tags: matlab, finite-difference, diffusion, implicit-methods

I'm running out of time for this code so any help would be greatly appreciated. I am currently coding the 2D heat/diffusion equation in matlab but i'm having trouble adding in the source term. my equation looks like this:

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \alpha_x \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \alpha_y \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} + Au \left( 1 - \frac{u}{K} \right)$$

I'm using Neumann bc's with the flux=0 everywhere. u is the population number, A, the Intrinsic growth rate and K the carrying capacity. The code I'm using is a code I found here that I've edited to use the implicit/BTCS method.

thank you so much.

```matlab
%%
%Specifying parameters
nx=40;                           %Number of steps in space(x)
ny=50;                           %Number of steps in space(y)       
nt=50;                           %Number of time steps 
dt=0.01;                         %Width of each time step
dx=2/(nx-1);                     %Width of space step(x)
dy=2/(ny-1);                     %Width of space step(y)
x=0:dx:2;                        %Range of x(0,2) and specifying the grid points
y=0:dy:2;                        %Range of y(0,2) and specifying the grid points
u=zeros(nx,ny);                  %Preallocating u
un=zeros(nx,ny);                 %Preallocating un
visx = 2;                        %Diffusion coefficient/viscocity
visy = 2;                        %Diffusion coefficient/viscocity
% RepRateA = 0.3;                %Intrinsic Growth Rate of Population
% CarCapK = 1.7;                 %Carrying Capacity of Environment 

UnW=0;                           %x=0 Neumann B.C (du/dn=UnW)
UnE=0;                           %x=L Neumann B.C (du/dn=UnE)
UnS=0;                           %y=0 Neumann B.C (du/dn=UnS)
UnN=0;                           %y=L Neumann B.C (du/dn=UnN)

%%
%Initial Conditions
for i=1:nx
    for j=1:ny
        if ((0.5<=y(j))&&(y(j)<=1.5)&&(0.5<=x(i))&&(x(i)<=1.5))
            u(i,j)=2;
        else
            u(i,j)=0;
        end
    end
end

%%
%B.C vector
bc=zeros(nx-2,ny-2);

bc(1,:)=-UnW/dx;       %Neumann B.Cs
bc(nx-2,:)=UnE/dx;     %Neumann B.Cs
bc(:,1)=-UnS/dy;       %Neumann B.Cs
bc(:,nx-2)=UnN/dy;     %Neumann B.Cs

%B.Cs at the corners:
bc=visx*dt*bc+visy*dt*bc;

%Calculating the coefficient matrix for the implicit scheme
Ex=sparse(2:nx-2,1:nx-3,1,nx-2,nx-2);
% Ax=Ex+Ex'-2*speye(nx-2);
Ax(1,1)=-1; 
Ax(nx-2,nx-2)=-1;                 %Neumann B.Cs
Ey=sparse(2:ny-2,1:ny-3,1,ny-2,ny-2);
% Ay=Ey+Ey'-2*speye(ny-2);
Ay(1,1)=-1; 
Ay(ny-2,ny-2)=-1;                 %Neumann B.Cs
A=kron(Ay/dy^2,speye(nx-2))+kron(speye(ny-2),Ax/dx^2);
D=speye((nx-2)*(ny-2))-visx*dt*A-visy*dt*A;
%%
%Calculating the field variable for each time step
i=2:nx-1;
j=2:ny-1;

for it=0:nt
    un=u;
    h=surf(x,y,u','EdgeColor','none');       %plotting the field variable
    shading interp
    axis ([0 2 0 2 0 2])
    title({['2-D Diffusion with alphax = ',num2str(visx)];['2-D Diffusion with alphay = ',num2str(visy)];['time (\itt) = ',num2str(it*dt)]})
    xlabel('Spatial co-ordinate (x) \rightarrow')
    ylabel('{\leftarrow} Spatial co-ordinate (y)')
    zlabel('Transport property profile (u) \rightarrow')
    drawnow; 
    refreshdata(h)

    %Implicit method:
    U=un;
    U(1,:)=[];
    U(end,:)=[];
    U(:,1)=[];
    U(:,end)=[];
    U=reshape(U+bc,[],1);
    U=D\U;
    U=reshape(U,nx-2,ny-2);
    u(2:nx-1,2:ny-1)=U;
%Neumann:
    u(1,:)=RepRateA*u(2,:)*(1-u(2,:).'/CarCapK)-UnW*dx;
    u(nx,:)=RepRateA*u(nx-1,:)*(1-u(nx-1,:).'/CarCapK)+UnE*dx;
    u(:,1)=RepRateA*u(:,2).'*(1-u(:,2)/CarCapK)-UnS*dy;
    u(:,ny)=RepRateA*u(:,ny-1).'*(1-u(:,ny-1)/CarCapK)+UnN*dy;
end
```

Comment: Not sure why it looks like this, I apologise. first time poster. hope the layout doesn't deter anyone

Comment: What's the issue you're having? I don't understand what you mean by 'having trouble adding in the source code'

Comment: @cbcoutinho I'm not sure where to code the term Au(1-u/K) nor how exactly i should go about doing it. also, if i were to change the diffusion coefficients (visx and visy) to variables or functions, how would i go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem in two ways: *explicitly* or *implicitly*.

If you want to solve your system *explicitly*, then the solution is quite simple: the only term you would be solving for is the $u_{i+1}$ term in the time derivative. All the other instances of $u$ are known quantities ($u_{i}$), which means they can be placed on the RHS - because they are knowns! To ensure numerical stability, the size of the time step should be small enough that the difference between $u_i$ and $u_{i+1}$ is small. The definition of *small* is not trivial in some cases. Most textbooks on PDEs will give you more information on what stable means w.r.t explicit solvers of PDEs. If you really want to get fancy you could set up your PDE into a system of ODEs in time and use one of the Matlab supplied ODE solvers (e.g. *ode45*, *ode15*, etc.). This has the added benefit of using *adaptive timesteps* because those Matlab routines are able to calculate the size of a timestep based on error measurements.

If you want to solve your equation *implicitly*, then you move into the world of *non-linear* PDEs, which require a non-linear solver within every time step. This is more expensive than explicit solvers *when using the same sized timestep*; however, implicit solvers are commonly more stable than explicit ones and can sometimes warrant the use of larger timesteps to speed up the solver. I noticed you wrote *implicit* in your code above: if that's what you decide to do then you would need to write a non-linear solver for your problem.

---

A rather simple non-linear implicit solver to implement is called the *Newton-Raphson method*, and may be useful for your problem.

If you don't want to implement a non-linear implicit solver, you may instead decide to implement a hybrid approach where you treat all *linear* terms *implicitly* and *non-linear* terms *explicitly*. What is best for solving your problem can only be determined by looking more closely at literature on the subject or experimentation. Since you're already working with the BTCS method, I would recommend extending it by including your source term explicitly into the RHS. This would result in a 'lag' of your source term with respect to time, but may be reasonable for your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. i would prefer to code it directly into the RHS but i've fiddled around with that on both U sections and the u section of the RHS, and both times i've received errors. so i'm not certain where exactly this should go.                                                                                                                                 When added to line 72 as un=RepRateA*u*(1-u.'/CarCapK) the error comes at line 89 {U=reshape(U+bc,[],1)} and says that "Matrix dimensions must agree".

Comment: When i code for U separately, i get the same error in line 89 as a mentioned above. 
Error in ==> 
    U(:,1)=[RepRateA*U(:,2)*(1-U(:,2).'/CarCapK)];
    U(:,end)=[RepRateA*U(:,end-1)*(1-U(:,end-1).'/CarCapK)] etc                                                                            but when I add the code in at u, (The last bit of code in the program) 
   u(:,1) = RepRateA*u(:,2)*(1-u(:,2).'/CarCapK)-UnS*dy 
  u(:,ny)=RepRateA*u(:,ny-1)*(1-u(:,ny-1).'/CarCapK)+UnN*dy etc   instead of an error i just have the results go haywire, especially at the boundaries

Comment: I don't the code you copied above is complete - there's no end statement associated with the for loop. I also don't see the line that you say is giving you problems `un=RepRateA*u...`. Make the code example above match the one you are using and it will make it easier to help you

Comment: As i previously stated, i wasn't sure where to include the term Au(1-u/K) so ln the example code i gave, i left it out.

Comment: after the for it=0:nt the next lione of code says un=u. when i change that to un=RepRateA*u*(1-u.'/CarCapK)  then the error "Matrix dimensions must agree" pops up.

Comment: I think the $u.'$ part is messing you up. Why do you put $'$ on the $u$? In Matlab that means _array transpose_, and if you multiple vector by its transpose you end up with a matrix (i.e. $[n \times 1] \cdot [1 \times n] = [n \times n]$). Something related to that would definitely give you a matrix dimension error

Comment: don't i need to transpose the matrix to multiply it by itself?

Comment: So i've retyped un=RepRateA*u*(1-u/CarCapK) and the result is that the graph ends up disappearing.. as far as i can tell it grows so large that it becomes to large to display on the axes.

Comment: Before adding the source term to your code, have you checked if it properly converges to a correct solution with respect to other boundary conditions? For diffusion problems you can try setting the initial condition to zero and dirchlect boundary conditions to one - in that scenario your domain should converge to one everywhere. If it does that, then you can try adding the source term again. If your current code works in the non-source case and doesn't work when there is the source, then you know where to look.

Comment: By the way, edit your question so that your entire code is represented, right now it doesn't work because there is no end statement on the for loop

Comment: aahh, i think that's a great idea. i'll check it out and report back. thanks so much!